# Javascript Object to get this of parent method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In the following `add` method of `myObj` how can I get `this` inside map? In other words, `this` when wrapped to map, points to that `anonymous` function inside map. How can I get `this` there?

> Note: Workarounds like creating a new variable `temp_sum`and adding
>   and returning are not preferred. Because, I might have to do some tests inside them using the **this** keyword.

```
var myObj = {

    sum        : 0,
    toAdd      : [2,3,4],
    add        : function(){

        this.toAdd.map(function(num){
           this.sum += num //<-- How to get this.sum from here           
        })

       return this.sum;

    }


};

var m = Object.create(myObj);
var _sum = m.add();
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = _sum;
```

Comment: Why not a `for` loop?

Comment: @Vld, Just working around map because it looks clean. Looks like should use for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bind`

```
var myObj = {

    sum        : 0,
    toAdd      : [2,3,4],
    add        : function(){

        this.toAdd.map(function(num, index){
           this.sum += num;
        }.bind(this))

       return this.sum;
    }
};
```

or `reduce`

```
var myObj = {

    sum        : 0,
    toAdd      : [2,3,4],
    add        : function(){
        this.sum = this.toAdd.reduce(function(a,b){
           return a + b;
        });

        return this.sum;
    }
};
```

or a `for` loop

```
var myObj = {

    sum        : 0,
    toAdd      : [2,3,4],
    add        : function(){
        for (var i=0; i<this.toAdd.length; i++) {
            this.sum += this.toAdd[i];
        }

        return this.sum;
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent. One more thing. It is not necessary but can is there a way to get Index of the item inside map?

Comment: Yes, `map` has three built in arguments, they are `map(currentValue, index, array)`

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method accepts optional argument: object value to be used as `this`. So your code will become as simple as:

```
add: function () {
    this.toAdd.map(function (num) {
        this.sum += num;      
    }, this);
    return this.sum;
}
```